# SQL Server Computed Column that doesn't affect existing data

Tags: sql-server

is that possible to do a computed column without affecting existing data?

I have a unique index column named

```
"BookingNo"
```

For newly insert Column I want it to be following this format

```
(format([CreationTime],'yyMMddHHmmssff'))
```

I tried used Computed Column but it modified all my existing data.

my existing BookingNo format was

```
201800123
```

Is there anyway to generate via database? Or we have insert via code?

Comment: Why would a computed column modify existing data?

Comment: A computed column almost by definition does not alter data. It's a "virtual" column that you can read (select) as some function of the other columns; you can't even write to it. Are you sure a computed column is what you want here? Perhaps edit your question to add more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_BookingNo DEFAULT(format(SYSDATETIME(),'yyMMddHHmmssff')) 
    FOR BookingNo
```

This way you will get the value only for newly created rows.

Please note that if this column has a unique constraint on it some inserts might fail if they are executed at the same time.

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks! We only allow 1 insert at a time at the moment

Comment: Glad to help :-)